# Using Dynamic Programming To Group Numbers

Tags: grouping, dynamic-programming, xor

Let's say you have a group of numbers. You need to eliminate numbers until there is only one left. This is hard to explain, so let me provide you with an example.

The numbers are 3, 6, 9, and 10.

You pair 3 with 9. You eliminate 3. (Note: either one of them could be eliminated). Now there are 6, 9, and 10 left. You pair 6 with 9. You eliminate 9. Now there are 6 and 10 left. You pair 6 with 10 (only option).

The problem is: I want to find the maximum value obtained from this elimination. Each time a number is eliminated, the XOR value of those two numbers is added to the count. In the previous example, the total value would be (3 ^ 6) + (6 ^ 9) + (6 ^ 10) = 10 + 15 + 12 = 37. This happens to be the maximum value that can be obtained from any elimination combination.

How would I solve this problem in Java with 2000 numbers? I know I can find every possible combination using brute force, but the run time of this was more than two seconds, and I prefer my solutions to be under two seconds. The only option left is Dynamic Programming.

Does anyone know how to solve this with Dynamic Programming?